# How can I input text in the email field on mobile login page using Test Rigor?

Tags: regex, testing, mobile, testrigor

I'm facing some issue on test rigor testcases.
I 'm testing mobile application on test rigor , Text is not being entered in the email field in the login page .
There is no placeholder in the email field . I am guessing that could be the issue .
In Web testing we can input id with the help of inspect the page , but how to do it in mobile testing , we can get any suggestion ?

I need to enter text in the email field .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8ezS.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: check that page contains " login " 
click on "login " button
wait 3 sec
check that page contains "Log in with"
Enter"kk@yopmail.com" into  "Email"
wait 3 sec

Answer (score -1):

You can try using testRigor's Optical character recognition, with the keyword
**using OCR only** checks the page without the source.

click "Email" using OCR only

This applies for **check that page contains "..."** commands as well.